# FOR VIEW SOQL for another user

Tags: apex, soql, analytics

Is it possible for me to use the FOR VIEW clause in SOQL for another user instead of the CurrentUser. For example I want to see how many records on the Case object a certain user has viewed in one day.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not possible out of box. SFDC does not allow you to track record views by default the way you described above "I want to see how many records on the Case object a certain user has viewed in one day".

So, you will have to use apex & VF. Here are steps for one of such simple implementation.

1. Create a object Case_views__c to track record view with 2 fields case_ID & user_ID
2. Create a vf page to show case details using  tag
3. In controller insert record in Case_views__c
4. Override case page detail view with this page VF page

Now every time user view case record SFDC will make entry in Case_views__c object.

You can then create a report to group by user and count the cases that they views in particulate time period

Comment: What about query access? Or Report views/exports? This is a very small piece of the puzzle, I think.

Comment: That is the whole point of FOR VIEW. To track which records have been viewed

Comment: @Bryan_Anderson_SL for view tracks the information in RecentlyViewed table, however, the table doesn't have the information on who viewed the data

Comment: @Bryan_Anderson_SL FOR VIEW only tracks ~200 records per object per user. If you want something more comprehensive, you need [Event Monitoring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm). This solution works well for UI views, which should be a reasonable approximation for average users.

Comment: @sfdcfox Record view is not tracked in event monitoring.

Comment: @AdrianLarson i don't agree to that as it was not posted in original post. I have build a feature like this and in my case it was just CSR efficiency was in focus.

Comment: @Bryan_Anderson_SL that is certainly not the point of for view.  It is used to add entry in recently viewed record. Here you need to track the all views and not only recently viewed record. right ? if not please take some effort and add full details on question.